# Google App Engine. How to see photos stored in BlobStore

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I stored several photos on app engine using BlobstoreService.

How to browse these photos ? I know that we can download each photo individually using its blob key, however there is no a way of accessing all photos from app engine console online to manage it ? (Delete for example...)  Or if i forgot the blob key how to get the picture/blob key back ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all blobs in your application using [The BlobInfo Class](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass):

```py
from google.appengine.ext import blobstore

for info in blobstore.BlobInfo.all():
    # do something with the blab
```